# array member gets set to null after returning it

Tags: php, arrays, return

I have a Function a, which looks something like this:

```
function a(){
    $myStr = "hello";
    $arrParams = array();

    $arrParams[] = "ssss";
    $arrParams[] = "%".$_GET["tbField1"]."%";

    echo implode(", ", $arrParams); //result: ssss, (textOfUserInput)

    $retArr = array($myStr, $arrParams);
    return $retArr;
}

$resArr = a();
echo $resArr[0]; //this one would still work
echo "hello" .$resArr[1] ."world";  //result: helloworld
```

if I execute this function, the echo prints out the two strings, which is supposed to be in there.

but if I call the function and save the returned array in a variable b, i have access to b[0], but b[1] remains empty.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: read this, then edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok thank you, done.

Comment: `$resArr[1]` (your `b`?) is an array. `$resArr[1][0]` would be `ssss` and `$resArr[1][1]` would be `%{textOfUserInput}%`.

Comment: Exactly, this is the behaviour I expected, but my Program pretends like $arrParams is empty!

Comment: from your code `$resArr[1]` can't be empty: https://3v4l.org/fT0gn - can you provide a _verifiable_ example of your problem?

Comment: No I'm afraid I can't. I've just tried it, but there is too much I need to change in order to get i working woithout sql... But at least you could assure me, that this part of logic should work. Thank you for that. If I have found my bug, I'll let you know. Thanks a lot for your effort!